# the Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The subset $Q_{8} := \{1,−1, i,−i, j,−j, k,−k \}$ of $\mathbb{H} $ is clearly a group under multiplication. It is called  **the quaternion group**.

> Can anyone help me?

1: What is the codimension of the augmentation ideal of a group algebra?

2:How  can we obtain Find the **Wedderburn** decomposition of $\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}]$.

Comment: If you have the software program GAP, you can use the wedderga package to find the decomposition you seek. I unfortunately do not. More details here: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/wedderga/doc/chap1.html

Answer (score 2):

The augmentation ideal is the kernel of the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\epsilon: \mathbb{C}[Q_8] \to \mathbb{C}$, defined on the basis of group elements by $\epsilon(g) = 1$ for each $g \in Q_8$. This map is clearly surjective, so $\ker \epsilon$ has codimension 1.

The Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$ can be found by knowing the dimensions of each irreducible representation of $Q_8$. This has four irreducible representations of dimension 1, and one of dimension 2. This gives the decomposition
$$ \mathbb{C}[Q_8] \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$$

as an isomorphism of rings.

Comment: Should we prove that $\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}]$ is the simisimple $F$-algebra?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-algebra for any finite group: this is called Maschke's theorem. The fact that the Wedderburn decomposition is related to its representation theory comes out of the general structure of finite-dimensional semisimple algebras.

Comment: why can`t we write?$$ \mathbb{C}[Q_8] \cong \mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$$